# Image picker not showing image iOS Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have created a simple application for image picker in Xcode 6.1.1 for iOS and it's working on Mac at my home but the same code is not working on Mac at my office Please can anyone tell me why is that ?

here is the github link for the source code of the same application.

https://github.com/varun-naharia/ImageUploader

***media info from computer 1 where everything working correctly***

```
2015-02-18 09:19:35.212 ImageUploader[3785:12959] info = {
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x7fd6f9d334a0> size {834, 1250} orientation 0 scale 1.000000";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=E2741A73-D185-44B6-A2E6-2D55F69CD088&ext=JPG";
}
2015-02-18 09:19:35.212 ImageUploader[3785:12959] mediaUrl = (null)
2015-02-18 09:19:35.212 ImageUploader[3785:12959] image = <UIImage: 0x7fd6f9d334a0> size {834, 1250} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
```

Comment: Running on an attached device or in the simulator? If in the simulator are you choosing the exact same device? Have you tried resetting the app in the simulator by deleting it (just like on a real device: long-tap then delete)?

Comment: I am running this on simulator and yes device is same but it doesn't matter because its working fine on all devices(simulator) at my home and yes I also tried resetting the simulator.

Comment: I downloaded and it ran fine for me using XCode 6.1.1 and testing w/ the iPhone 6. There is not much in your program to go wrong. Can you better describe what fails? That is, what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: everything is working fine just image not visible after I choose it from the gallery the UIImageView is still empty.

Comment: This is really a more a question about debugging an iOS app (or, arguably, any software). In this case set a breakpoint in the delegate function didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. You want to see what was returned in the dictionary. You can do that by logging it: NSLog(@"info: %@", info); You can and should also step through and look at your variables. In this case the mediaURL remains nil but the dictionary (info) shows that there is are three keys: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType, UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage, and UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL. Are those keys on your 2nd computer?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts I will let you know when I will check that

Comment: Problem is in simulator don't know may be because have previously xcode 5.1 and installed 6.1 without replacing it then i deleted 5.1 because I face some problem. This Code is working fine xcode 6  I tested by removing xcode 6.1 and installing xcode 6. I tried everything to clean xcode but not working in 6.1

Comment: Can you please give me working image upload code for xcode 6.1

Comment: Your code works for me on XCode 6.1. Please add in the logging function from a couple comments ago and let me know what the output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating xcode it is now working fine